# CSS Code for Image before Menu[Wordpress]

Tags: css, wordpress

My WP Theme gives me a block where I can build in Custom CSS. I need a picture with the right size and not as background before the .primarymenu.

Comment: Sorry for my writing mistakes, I'm from Austria and a student. Please give me an answer!

Comment: You need to provide more information. We have no idea what theme you are using, let alone what code the theme has! See here -> [mcve]

Comment: you can only insert background elements of a content with :before, if you want to create a real image tag you cannot do that with css.

Comment: I use veggie lite @CalvT

Comment: And what do u mean with real image tag? @vico

Answer (score 0):

With CSS you can do that this way:

```css
.menu:before {
  content: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=23&bg=990000&txt=Image&w=150&h=150');
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">Menu</div>
```

Comment: The picture is like an background. On my 2nd monitor is the picture in the Menu and not next to.